# Unable to read value from Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement a recaptcha on a login page.
But every time it hits the code , a null reference exception happens.
I'm using asp.net with the default login template, it has its own Web.Config(not sure why though)

Is there a setting that needs to be done?Below are my codes.Hope to get a reply soon.

**aspx file**

```
<%@ Page Title="Log In" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Penerangan.Emedia2u.Web.Account.Login" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>

<asp:Label Visible="false" ID="lblResult" runat="server" />
                    <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" runat="server" />
```

**.cs file**

```
  recaptcha.PublicKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reCAPTCHAPublicKey"].ToString();
                recaptcha.PrivateKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reCAPTCHAPrivateKey"].ToString();
```

**web.config file**

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="reCAPTCHAPublicKey" value="fromgooglecaptchakey"/>
    <add key="reCAPTCHAPrivateKey" value="fromgooglecaptchakey"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: `<add key="reCAPTCHAPrivateKey" value="value="fromgooglecaptchakey"/>"/>` is that a typo?

Comment: sadly it was a typo; edited , question still remains though

Comment: I have a hunch that app.config is a different code path than web.config. You'll need the System.Web.Configuration references for web.config.

Comment: The return is a string, so the ToString() isn't needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it works on my code:

```
using System.Web.Configuration;

/* ... */

WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reCAPTCHAPublicKey"];
```

you'll need to make sure the web config is opened somewhere on the backend of your asp.net project. See the MSDN article for info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig1 =
                System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
```

Comment: still the same :/
tried something like these , still the same result
1. WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reCAPTCHAPublicKey"].ToString();

2. WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reCAPTCHAPublicKey"]

Comment: Check web.config structure? Should be <configuration><appSettings> ... </appSettings></configuration>